# Tornado timeout block all services

Tags: python, timeout, tornado

I create a simple test app to check timeout in tornado 
    import tornado.ioloop
    import tornado.web

```
class LoopHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        while (True):
            print ("in loop")
        self.write("Loop, Handler")

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
        (r"/loop", LoopHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Then I call http://localhost:8888/loop the endpoint never response because the infinite loop the problems is that http://localhost:8888/ not responding either. the question is why this happened and how can solve this?

**EDIT**

Update code that solve the problemn

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


@unblock
class LoopHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        while (True):
            print ("in loop")
        return "Loop, Handler"

@unblock        
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        return "Hello, world"

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
        (r"/loop", LoopHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()

#unblock.py   
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial, wraps

EXECUTOR = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)


def unblock(f):

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        self = args[0]

        def callback(future):
            self.write(future.result())
            self.finish()

        EXECUTOR.submit(
            partial(f, *args, **kwargs)
        ).add_done_callback(
            lambda future: tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(
                partial(callback, future)))

    return wrapper
```

Comment: Well, you can call `LoopHandler` exactly 4 times :) then your server is blocking again.

Comment: @YannicHamann thanks you are rigth I still try to create a better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are basics of async programming. To point you in the right direction take a look at the [reactor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) and especially at the event loop.

> The reactor pattern is one implementation technique of event-driven
>   architecture. In simple terms, it uses a single threaded event loop
>   blocking on resource-emitting events and dispatches them to
>   corresponding handlers and callbacks.

Both functions `LoopHandler` and `MainHandler` are processed in the same event loop, therefore `MainHandler` gets queued but never executed since the event loop is busy executing `LoopHandler`.

One of the challenges (at least for me) in async programming is to be careful about blocking calls like database operations with for example `SQLAlchemy`, file operations, expensive calculations, etc. There are some interesting approaches using thread pools to solve this but you won't need them to get you started.

*Ah, and in case you stumbling over the first sentence of the wiki article  I have linked take a look [here](https://joearms.github.io/images/con_and_par.jpg) to understand the difference between **parallel** and **concurrent**. It helped me a lot.*